# PyQt5 QLineEdit как изменить

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt5, qlineedit

Допустим у меня есть QLineEdit.

```
self.line = QLineEdit()
```

Я занёс его в массив mas

```
mas = []
mas.append(self.line)
```

как теперь изменить текст этого виджета. `mas[0].text = ...` не помогает.

Comment: Не понятна ваша идея создания массива, элемент которого будет виджет?

Answer (score 1):

```
mas[0].setText('...')
```

[вот документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html)

Answer (score 0):

У QLineEdit есть метод .setText() и text(), если вам нужно "достать" текст из поля.
Также с помощью изменения стиля возможно изменить шрифт, толщину текста, цвет и многое другое.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUi()

def initUi(self):
    self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

    self.edit1 = QLineEdit()

    self.edit1.setText('This is first edit')

    self.edit1.setStyleSheet('background : #f0f0f0; font-weight: 500; color: red; font-size:12pt;')

    self.edit2 = QLineEdit()

    self.edit2.setText('This is second edit')

    self.edit2.setStyleSheet('background : #00001f; font-weight: 500; color: #d5d5d5; font-size: 10pt;')

    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.edit1)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.edit2)
    self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

app = QApplication([])

e = Example()

e.show()
```